# WSS4J Encoding type in NONCE missing (Loadrunner Java)

Tags: java, encoding, wss4j, nonce

I have a java script for a webservice where the encoding type in nonce is missing. Where is the mistake in the script?

```
    WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader();
    secHeader.insertSecurityHeader(doc);
    // create the username token builder and configure it
    WSSecUsernameToken usernameTokenizer = new WSSecUsernameToken();
    usernameTokenizer.addCreated();
    usernameTokenizer.addNonce();
    usernameTokenizer.setPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_DIGEST); 

    usernameTokenizer.build(doc, secHeader);
    String requestWithHeader = XMLUtils.PrettyDocumentToString(doc);
```

It should be like this...

```
 <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 
 200401-wss-soap-message-security- 
 1.0#Base64Binary">rgSCc2eR6kTK2T+xnkMxYw== 
 </wsse:Nonce>
```

But it is like this...

```
 <wsse:Nonce>3sMhSW3wqOWi2vLn8ffgEQ==</wsse:Nonce>
```